# How to edit WordPress theme, change content which is in english in another language?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, themes

I started to built a ecommerce in WooCommerce, but i have a problem, i have to change some strings from english in my language.
How to change lables in form por check, how to change sort form labels, i want to rename labels in my language, not only labels, also check out, some buttons?

I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Loco translator plugin: https://localise.biz/

You'll have to generate a .po for your language.

But also go to change the language in settings:

[image]

Hope this helps.